# Time complexity of one dimensional and two dimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, time, time-complexity

Take for example taking input from the user for a one-dimensional array of size n, we know it's time complexity is O(n).

```
for(i=0;i<n;i=i+1)
     {
         scanf("%d",&a[i]);
     }
```

Now if the array is two dimensional, the time complexity is O(n^2)

```
for(i=0;i<n;i=i+1)
{
   for(j=0;j<n;j=j+1)
   {
       scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
   }
}
```

But even the two dimensional array is saved in the same manner as the one-dimensional array. It is essentially just an increase in size, why is there a difference?

Comment: The inner loop is run `n` times, and the contents of the inner loop will be executed `n` times, thus the content of the inner loop will execute `n*n` = `n to the power of 2` times.

Comment: you are processing all of the elements of one array (`n` elements) for each element of the other array (`n` elements). `n * n = n ^ 2`.

Comment: in memory not always have to be the same,  and depending on hoy they are can have very different access costs

Comment: @owacoder I understand that, but since a one-dimensional and two-dimensional array store the elements in the same manner, two dimensional array can be thought of a one-dimensional array with large size.
Anyhow I understood the point made by Haris. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in the time complexity is because of the number of elements you are storing.

For a linear 1D array, you are storing `n` elements in a linear way, and it is getting stored in a linear way too. So time complexity is `O(n)`

For a 2D array, lets suppose you are storing `m` elements, which are actually stored in a linear way only in the memory. But, what you work with are the elements divided into rows (and columns). Now for instance, the size of each row and column is `n`, then you are reading `n*n` elements, which is nothing but `m` elements only (`m == n*n`). So the complexity is `O(m)` or `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 1):

sort of a perceptual issue, since if you have n elements it would be O(n) either way, but if you are measuring based on one of the array dimensions you aren't going to be n^2 unless it is a square matrix (I see that yours is)... so better to think of it as O(h*w) or just 0(n) anyway...